# `doublespacing` environment application onto the typographical properties

Tags: line-spacing, setspace

I'm just working on a tex file to build a personal template. In the case of the title, I'm gonna increase the space between lines of the title. So, just tying to use `setspace` package and `doublespacing` environment, as below:

```
\documentclass[•]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage
[
        a4paper,% other options: a3paper, a5paper, etc
        left=2cm,
        right=2cm,
        top=3cm,
        bottom=4cm,
        vmargin=2cm,
        % use vmargin=2cm to make vertical margins equal to 2cm.
        % us  hmargin=3cm to make horizontal margins equal to 3cm.
        % use margin=3cm to make all margins  equal to 3cm.
]
{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{doublespacing}

    \textbf{\Huge{the title of the template, is which supposed to include a long succession of characters and be splitted into different lines.}}   

\end{doublespacing}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

But, the expected outcome does not appear, and the space is still as the same...

What's the problem with such application of the environment onto a bold and huge piece of text?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `setspace` for this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,% other options: a3paper, a5paper, etc
  left=2cm,
  right=2cm,
  top=3cm,
  bottom=4cm,
  %vmargin=2cm, %% What for? You already set top and bottom
]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\linespread{1.5}\Huge\bfseries

The title of the template, is which supposed to
include a long succession of characters and be
split into different lines.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Decide the value to pass `\linespread` yourself.

I'm not showing the result, because it's awful.

---

What's your error? First, the environment is called `doublespace`. Second, the title *is* doublespaced, but, since you end the effect of `\Huge` before the paragraph is split into lines, the normal baselineskip (but doubled because of `\doublespacing`) is used.

Beware: `\Huge` and the other size declarations are not commands with an argument and a paragraph must end in the scope of the declaration. Thus

```
\begin{doublespace}
\centering
\bfseries\Huge

The long title

\end{doublespace}
```

would do the job. But it's using a gun to kill a mosquito.

Comment: It did work, perfectly. Thanks...
Would you please, kindly, declare that what wrong is with my own used method?!... Seemingly, that should have worked, technically, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Roboticist I added the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Remove any pairs of braces and use the correct name of the environment:

```
\documentclass[•]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage
[
        a4paper,% other options: a3paper, a5paper, etc
        left=2cm,
        right=2cm,
        top=3cm,
        bottom=4cm,
        vmargin=2cm,
        % use vmargin=2cm to make vertical margins equal to 2cm.
        % us hmargin=3cm to make horizontal margins equal to 3cm.
        % use margin=3cm to make all margins equal to 3cm.
]
{geometry}

\begin{document}


\begin{doublespace}
\centering

   \bfseries\Huge the title of the template, is which supposed to include a long succession of characters and be split into different lines.

\end{doublespace}

\end{document}
```

[image]